# Unable to insert data into MS Access database from Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, database-engine

just a beginner in Programing ...
I use a class to handle the connectionstring .

public class DataBase
    {
       public OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
       public OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

```
   public void getConnection()
   {
       con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Project\Database\DataBase.mdb";

   }

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBase db = new DataBase();
        db.getConnection();


        string Name = txtCostumerName.Text;
        string DayorNight = cboSwimming.Text;
        string Adult1 = txtAdultCount.Text;
        string Kid = txtKidsCount.Text;
        string Cottage1 = cboCottageType.Text;
        string Room = cboRoomType.Text;
        string Total1 = lblCottageTotal.Text;
        string Cash1 = txtCashRecieve.Text;
        string Change1 = txtChange.Text;
        db.con.Open();
       OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand ("INSERT INTO  TicketAndCottage (Cotumer_Name , Swimming, Adult, Kids, Cottage, Room , Total, Cash, Change) Values(@Name , @DayorNight , @Adult1 ,@Kid , @Cottage1 , @Room, @Total1 , @Cash1 , @Change1)");
        command.Connection = db.con;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


        if (db.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Cotumer_Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Name;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Swimming", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = DayorNight;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Adult", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Adult1;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Kids", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Kid;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Cottage", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Cottage1;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Room", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Room;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Total", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Total1;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Cash", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Cash1;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Change", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Change1;

            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
                db.con.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                //db.con.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
        }
    }
```

and when i click the button i got "Microsoft JET Database Engine"

Comment: Check OLEDB engine version in your connection string along with machine architecture. Jet OLEDB provider and your application architecture should match.

Comment: I hope you know that the default for Visual Studio is to copy the db to its own folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more context (such as what your connection string and data context look like), I can only take a guess.

One issue appears to be a typo in the field below called "Cotumer_Name". Your text box is named "CostumerName" with an S in there.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand 
    ("INSERT INTO  TicketAndCottage (Cotumer_Name , Swimming, Adult, Kids, Cottage, Room , Total, Cash, Change) 
                              Values(@Name , @DayorNight , @Adult1 ,@Kid , @Cottage1 , @Room, @Total1 , @Cash1 , @Change1)");
```

It'd be helpful to include some more code.

Comment: Access uses position, not name for external SQL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out whats wrong

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataBase db = new DataBase();
            db.getConnection();
            db.con.Open();

            string Name = txtCostumerName.Text;
            string DayorNight = cboSwimming.Text;
            string Adult1 = txtAdultCount.Text;
            string Kid = txtKidsCount.Text;
            string Cottage1 = cboCottageType.Text;
            string Room = cboRoomType.Text;
            double Total1 = Convert.ToDouble(lblCottageTotal.Text);
            double Cash1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtCashRecieve.Text);
            double Change1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtChange.Text);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO  TicketAndCottage (Costumer_Name , Swimming, Adult, Kids, Cottage, Room , Total, Cash, Change) Values(@Name , @DayorNight , @Adult1 ,@Kid , @Cottage1 , @Room, @Total1 , @Cash1 , @Change1)", db.con);

            if (db.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@Costumer_Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Name;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Swimming", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DayorNight;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Adult", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Adult1;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Kids", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Kid;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Cottage", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Cottage1;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Room", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Room;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Total", OleDbType.Double, 50).Value = Total1;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Cash", OleDbType.Double, 50).Value = Cash1;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Change", OleDbType.Double, 50).Value = Change1;

                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    db.con.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                    // db.con.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
            }
}
```