# How to save successfully data into access?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How can I get this query to work properly? I can not save any of the data to the database, keep getting error: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

[this helped a lot too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823674/unable-to-insert-data-into-ms-access-database-from-visual-c-sharp)

Data Types was my issue, thank you guys!

Comment: Does table *SetUp_Track* include only those 6 fields mentioned in the question?

Comment: those are the only fields plus the ID set to AutoNumber on the database,I was fearing it was the Last_Good_Time & First_Good_Time I am not sure if I am passing the data type correctly to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using named parameter:

```
ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO SetUp_Track (Operat, Maching, Last_Good_Time, First_Good_Time, Post_Number, Created) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", con);
```

Also,

All parameters in .Parameters.AddWithValue are sent with type of String,

check if all of these parameters are defined as String type in db too,

For example if Post_Number is Integer in db then you should cast the String to Integer and then use .Parameters.AddWithValue

```
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post_Number", Convert.ToInt32(Post_NumberTxtbx.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you guys I had found I had a couple of parenthesis I forgot to close; however, I am still getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: @HGtez Did you try our solutions?!

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if I am passing the data correctly to the DB from my form, I've attached the DB I am using. tHank you

Comment: Check this link for DateTime parameters: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552262/passing-a-datetime-value-as-a-parameter-to-an-oledbcommand)

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot GREAT WORK!

Answer (score 1):

The `VALUES` clause should be a list of items enclosed in parentheses, `()`.  Yours omitted the closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem is to forget to use `)` at the end of `VALUES` part.

```
INSERT INTO SetUp_Track
values(@Operat, @Maching, @Last_Good_Time,
@First_Good_Time, @Post_Number, @Created
                                        ^here
```

Always try your command in your database manager first. But more important, `OleDbCommand` does not accept named parameters.

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder <strike>must</strike> should be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

Comment: That page gets quoted a lot. Unfortunately it is misleading when it says that "the question mark (?) placeholder **must** be used" (emphasis mine). It really should say that "the question mark (?) placeholder *should* be used". The `?` placeholder is not an absolute requirement. Named parameters *do* work, but the names are irrelevant; it's still the *position* of the parameters in the CommandText and the *order* in which they are added that matters. (And that's why I maintain that `?` *should* be used, to prevent people from getting the wrong idea.)

Comment: @GordThompson Yeah, you are totally right. Using `?` is just a comman approach for parameterize of an `OleDbCommand`. Names are totally ignored. The only matter is their orders.